# How to grant access to only the routes defined?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have the following code defined in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/ListVehicles", "/vehicle-list");
});
```

How do I only allow access to the page by using the url "vehicle-list" instead of just typing the cshtml file name ListVehicles in the url? I tried options.Conventions.Clear() but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with custom `IPageRouteModelConvention` that clears `Selectors` list in required `PageRouteModel`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRouteModelConvention("/ListVehicles", model =>
    {
        model.Selectors.Clear();
    });
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/ListVehicles", "vehicle-list");
});
```

Now request to http://localhost/ListVehicles will result to 404 error, while request to http://localhost/vehicle-list will return `ListVehicles.cshtml` page.